# Laravel, Eloquent. Вывести из таблицы записи с определенным ключом (датой)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel, orm, eloquent

Имеется база данных с датой, которая в формате 11/2020 (месяц/год). Мне необходимо выводить данные скажем от 09/2020 по 03/2022. Каким способом это можно реализовать? Eloquent отдельно, без Laravel. В другой формат даты переделать невозможно.

Comment: Надо выполнять отбор не по исходному значению поля, а по выражению, которое преобразует исходное `%m/%Y` в, например, `%Y%m`. Ну и с критерием проделать ту же операцию. PS. Это не дата.

Comment: можно сгенерить еще строки для всего периода, и использовать IN

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
$start = '12/2020';
$end = '03/2022';

Model::whereIn('date', datesArray($start, $end))->get();

function datesArray($start, $end): array
{
    $startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(str_replace('/', '.', "01/$start"));
    $endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(str_replace('/', '.', "01/$end"));

    $datesArray = [];
    for($startDate, $endDate; $startDate->lessThanOrEqualTo($endDate); $startDate->addMonth()) {
        $format = $startDate->format('m/Y');
        array_push($datesArray, $format);
    }
    return $datesArray;
}
```